# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-console

i'm making login application with firebase, I enabled Email/password and google providers both are working perfectly on Api less than 31 but on levels above that google works but Email/password doesn't and i don't know the problem.
What i tried to do :
-updated all dependencies to last version.
-added implementation `'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'`
-and every solution I found.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKiOp.png)

```
class AuthenticationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityAuthenticationBinding
private val viewModel by viewModels<LoginViewModel>()

companion object {
    const val TAG = "LoginFragment"
    const val SIGN_IN_RESULT_CODE = 1001
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityAuthenticationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    binding.authButton.setOnClickListener { launchSignInFlow() }

    viewModel.authenticationState.observe(this) { authenticationState ->
        when (authenticationState) {
            LoginViewModel.AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED -> switchActivities()
            else -> Log.e(
                TAG,
                "Authentication state that doesn't require any UI change $authenticationState"
            )
        }
    }
}

private fun launchSignInFlow() {
    val providers = arrayListOf(
        EmailBuilder().build(), GoogleBuilder().build()
    )

    startActivityForResult(
        AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build(), AuthenticationActivity.SIGN_IN_RESULT_CODE
    )
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_RESULT_CODE) {
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            startActivity(Intent(this@AuthenticationActivity, MyApp::class.java))
            finish()
            return
        } else {
            if (response == null) {
                Log.e("Login", "Login canceled by User")
                return
            }
            if (response.error!!.errorCode == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                Log.e("Login", "No Internet Connection")
                return
            }
            if (response.error!!.errorCode == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                Log.e("Login", "Unknown Error")
                return
            }
        }
        Log.e("Login", "Unknown sign in response")
    }
}

private fun switchActivities() {
    val switchActivityIntent = Intent(this, RemindersActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(switchActivityIntent)
}
```

}

```
private fun sendNotification(triggeringGeofences: List<Geofence>) {

    triggeringGeofences.forEach {
        val requestId = it.requestId

        val remindersRepository: ReminderDataSource by inject()
        //Interaction to the repository has to be through a coroutine scope
        CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch(SupervisorJob()) {
            //get the reminder with the request id
            val result = remindersRepository.getReminder(requestId)
            if (result is Result.Success<ReminderDTO>) {
                val reminderDTO = result.data
                //send a notification to the user with the reminder details
                sendNotification(
                    this@GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService, ReminderDataItem(
                        reminderDTO.title,
                        reminderDTO.description,
                        reminderDTO.location,
                        reminderDTO.latitude,
                        reminderDTO.longitude,
                        reminderDTO.id
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using firebase notifications?

Comment: using notifications but not from firebase. regular sendNotification fun

Comment: Can you please post that code?

Comment: entered the image in the post

Comment: Sir image doesn't contain the code that is creating the crash. I want to check the notification code that you have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

That was an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1999) on older versions of FirebaseUI for Android. It has been fixed in [version 8.0.2](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases/tag/8.0.2). Please update the dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'
```